# In Rails testing / rspec what is the difference between `request: true` and `type: request`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, integration-testing

I've been looking over tests and I've seen `request: true` and `type: request` used, seemingly interchangeably.

I was wondering what the difference between them are and if there is any, and which the correct format is to use. I'm finding it quite hard to find the docs or any info on these two settings, if someone could point me to that too that would be fantastic thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`type: :request` is just [metadata](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.3/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Metadata.html) but it has special significance as it will cause RSpec::Rails to base the spec off `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` which provides the helpers for sending HTTP requests among many other things.

```
RSpec.describe "Foo", type: :request do
  context "Bar", baz: "Hello World" do
    it "has metadata" do
      expect(example.metadata[:baz]).to eq "Hello World"
      expect(example.metadata[:type]).to eq :request
    end
  end
end
```

I have never actually seen `request: true` be used and it's not [used in the documentation](https://rspec.info/features/6-0/rspec-rails/request-specs/request-spec/) or generators so it's fair to say that this is the "wrong" way.

Alternatively RSpec::Rails has a `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` method that can let you omit the explicit type declarion.

Comment: `type: :request` and `request: true` are the same thing. See [`RSpec::Core::Metadata::build_from_hash`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/main/lib/rspec/core/metadata.rb#L80): *"Used internally to build a hash from an args array. **Symbols are converted into hash keys with a value of `true`.**This is done to support simple tagging using a symbol, rather than needing to do `:symbol => true`."*

Comment: @engineersmnky I suspected it was something like that. I really don't see the point though if the generators are used.

Comment: I agree; however, not everyone uses generators. I just thought the comment rounded out the answer for "what the difference between them are and if there is any": There is no difference and "which the correct format is to use": I would say `type: :request` since the docs do state: "This is done to support simple tagging using a symbol, rather than needing to do `:symbol => true` and as you pointed out the official documentation does not utilize the later approach.